# How to pass index of array in cmd line argument which is function pointer and call to specific function in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, function-pointers

Suppose I have 2 functions in Perl. I would create a array of references of that two  functions. & in command line argument I'll pass only that index of array which call specific function and if I don't give any argument then it'll call all functions which referenced were in array(Default case).

So, can any help me to do this?

```
## Array content function pointers
my @list= {$Ref0,$Ref1 }


my $fun0Name = “fun0”;
my $Ref0 =&{$fun0Name}();

my $fun1Name = “fun1”;
my $Ref1 =&{$fun1Name}();

#### Two functions

sub fun0() {
   print "hi \n";
}

sub fun1() {
   print "hello \n";
}

##### Now in cmd argument if i passed Test.pl -t 0(index of array ,means call to 1st function)
##### if i give test.pl -t (No option ) ....then i call both function.
```

Comment: This is pretty vague.  Can you show some code you have?

Comment: sub foo { 
    print "hi \n";
}

sub bar { 
    print "fagun \n";
}

my $foo_ref = \&foo;
my $bar_ref = \&bar;

my @array = ( $foo_ref, $bar_ref );

#Reading arguments from the command line is pretty easy:

my $arg = shift @ARGV;

#Looking things up in an array is also pretty easy:

my $item = $array[$arg];

   foreach my $item1(@array)
           {   
                if($item1 eq $item)
                {   
                    ## How I Call now specific function after comparison with reference ?
                    last;
          }
                
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a function pointer (called a code reference in Perl) is easy enough:

```
sub foo { 
    say "foo!";
}

sub bar { 
    say "bar!";
}

my $foo_ref = \&foo;
my $bar_ref = \&bar;
```

Putting things in an array is pretty easy:

```
my @array = ( $foo_ref, $bar_ref );
```

Reading arguments from the command line is pretty easy:

```
my $arg = shift @ARGV;
```

Looking things up in an array is also pretty easy:

```
my $item = $array[$arg];
```

Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: foreach my $item1(@array)
           {   
                if($item1 eq $item)
                {   
                    ## How I Call now specific function after comparison with reference ?
                    last;
          }
                
            }